# Getting the address of function return arguement in C

Tags: c, pointers

Having read the chapter about sttructures from "The C programming Language book" I tried the following code. The goal is to have an array of pointer initialized with some specific value for all its points.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXPOINTS 1000

struct point {
    int x;
    int y;
};

struct point makepoint(int x, int y);

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    int number1 = 5, number2 = 10;
    struct point *points[1000];

    for (i=0; i< MAXPOINTS; i++) {
        points[i]  = &(makepoint(number1, number2));
    }
}

struct point makepoint(int x, int y) {
    struct point my_point;
    my_point.x = x;
    my_point.y = y;
    return my_point;
}
```

The error generated after running the above code is the following:

```
test_something.c:18:22: error: cannot take the address of an rvalue of type 'struct point'
```

Why does this happen since the makepoint function does return a valid point object?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: note, even if this was legal it would cause UB because the value returned from the function ceases to exist after the current statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning a temporary *copy* of a point and take his address is not a good idea.
Try this:

```
struct point* makepoint(int x, int y);

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    int i;
    int number1 = 5, number2 = 10;
    struct point* points[MAXPOINTS];

    for (i=0; i< MAXPOINTS; i++)
        points[i]  = makepoint(number1, number2);

    for (i=0; i< MAXPOINTS; i++)
        free(points[i]);
    return 0;
}

struct point* makepoint(int x, int y) {
    struct point* my_point = malloc(sizeof(struct point));
    my_point->x = x;
    my_point->y = y;
    return my_point;
}
```

Anyway, in your code:

```
struct point *points[10];

for (i=0; i< MAXPOINTS; i++) {
    points[i]  = &(makepoint(number1, number2));
}
```

...you have an array of 10 pointers and you're trying to assign 1000 pointers (MAXPOINTS).

Comment: Seems like this answer and the answer above has everythingy explained in a much better way than mine :-). Good catch also, regarding array size.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot take the address of a value, only of a variable. This is because values don't necessarily need to live in (addressable) memory. For example: the return value of a function is (usually) passed via a register, and you cannot take the address of a register(-variable).

You could instead change your `makepoint` function to take a pointer to a `struct point` and fill it in:

```
struct point makepoint(struct point * in, int x, int y){
    in->x = x;
    in->y = y;
    return *in;
}
```

Note that the return value isn't strictly necessary, but kept for 'backward compatability'.